# If $G$ is a group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, prove that $G$ has subgroups of order $p$ and $q$?

Tags: group-theory

This question confuses me greatly. How do we even know that there *are* subgroups in the first place if all we know about $G$ is that it is a group of order $pq$, where p and q are distinct primes?

I know that by Lagrange's theorem the order of any subgroup must divide the order of the group itself (and we get subgroups of order $p$ and $q$ from that) but how do we know these subgroups *exist* in the first place?

Comment: Cf. [Sylow theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems)

Comment: Use Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: This is easy to prove for cyclic groups. if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $pq$, then it has subgroups of order $p$ and $q$. This one follows because $G$ has a generator element, say $w$. The first subgroup would be $\{x: x=w^{qn};  0<n<p\}$ and the second  one $\{x: x=w^{pn};  0<n<q\}$ But for a more complicated groups you can refer to Sylow's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the converse of Lagrange's theorem is false in general. 
If $G$ is a finite group such $d$ divides the order of the group, then $G$ does not necessarily contain a subgroup of order $d$.

However, the converse is true if $d$ is prime. You can search for proof of Cauchy's theorem as Geoffrey Trang commented or try to prove it by yourself.

Hint : $ |G| = |H| [G:H]$

This result also follows from Sylow theorems as well but that will come much further in the book.