# Possible structure of group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes *but* neither $P$ nor $Q$ is normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a some confusion regarding the accepted answer solution here: [Structure of groups of order $pq$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502186/structure-of-groups-of-order-pq-where-p-q-are-distinct-primes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Consider a group $G$ with order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Let $P$ be a subgroup of $G$ with order $p$ and $Q$ be a subgroup with order $q$ (from Sylow's theorems we know these exist cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549660/if-g-is-a-group-of-order-pq-where-p-and-q-are-distinct-primes-prove-th)). The assumption $q \pmod p \neq 1$ implies $P$ is normal in $G$ and $p \pmod q \neq 1$ implies that $Q$ is normal in $G$. We need at least one of these assumptions to write $G$ as a semi-direct product of $P$ and $Q$. The accepted solution to the other questions does that.

**But what happens if neither of these assumptions hold true, and neither $P$ nor $Q$ is normal in $G$?** Then we can no longer write $G\cong C_p\rtimes C_q$ or $G\cong C_q\rtimes C_p$ (because for writing a group as a semi-direct product of its subgroups, at least one of the subgroups must be normal cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)). **How would the group structure look in that case and how to write a mathematical description of it?** The accepted answer does not deal that case and I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

**Perhaps at least one of the subgroups $P$ or $Q$ simply *has to be* normal? But why?**

Comment: If neither $P$ nor $Q$ is normal, then perhaps, $G$ might be a [Zappa-Szep product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product) of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Maybe, but I think it's more probable that in this context the subgroup $P$ (s.t. $p > q$) is necessarily normal as hinted by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/881992). I just don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation where neither $P$ nor $Q$ is normal never occurs. This is because if $q \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $1<p<q$, so $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod q$.